# Fabric BETA updated, now I can't install my app, neither BETA, Android Studio or apk

Tags: android, apk, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-beta

I just updated to the latest version of BETA. and now I get this when I try to install the app:

```
 DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/nl.hgrams.passenger"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/nl.hgrams.passenger
```

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]

```
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall nl.hgrams.passenger
```

DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR

Any ideeas?

PS: This is what the log says when I try to install from BETA:

```
11-12 17:48:06.576: E/installd(200): Couldn't opendir /data/data/nl.hgrams.passenger: No such file or directory
11-12 17:48:06.577: W/PackageManager(788): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/nl.hgrams.passenger-1
11-12 17:48:06.577: W/PackageManager(788): com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerException: Can't install because provider name com.google.android.gms.measurement.google_measurement_service (in package nl.hgrams.passenger) is already used by io.crash.air
11-12 17:48:06.577: W/PackageManager(788):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.scanPackageDirtyLI(PackageManagerService.java:6812)
11-12 17:48:06.577: W/PackageManager(788):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.scanPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:6487)
11-12 17:48:06.577: W/PackageManager(788):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installNewPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:11772)
11-12 17:48:06.577: W/PackageManager(788):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:12397)
11-12 17:48:06.577: W/PackageManager(788):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.-wrap25(PackageManagerService.java)
11-12 17:48:06.577: W/PackageManager(788):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$9.run(PackageManagerService.java:10156)
11-12 17:48:06.577: W/PackageManager(788):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-12 17:48:06.577: W/PackageManager(788):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-12 17:48:06.577: W/PackageManager(788):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-12 17:48:06.577: W/PackageManager(788):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
11-12 17:48:06.577: W/PackageManager(788):  at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

Comment: I have also the problem that I cannot install the BETA app anymore, I started a thread in the official support community. Check it out here: https://twittercommunity.com/t/cannot-install-new-beta-app-version-on-android/56213/4 Regards,
Tobias

Comment: Thanks!! I hope they find a fix for this soon. I can't even install from Android Studio, and I don't want to factory reset my phone. I have too much data I don't want to lose, just because they are not able to test..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was fixed, in the latest update from Crashlytics.
This is their thread on the problem:
https://twittercommunity.com/t/cannot-install-new-beta-app-version-on-android/56213/4

Comment: please don't put link we can't access